# Color the empty cells between two cells that have a specific value

Tags: excel

For example: in a row(A1:Z1) I have A1=1, D1=1, and F1=2, K1=2, and O1=3, U1=3

I want a conditional format that will color the empty cells based on the values of the cell ranges A to D, then from F to K and finally from O to U.

I'm using the following formatting and it works with cells that have a value of 1, but it isn't working for 2, 3 or any other cell values.

=COUNTIF(A1:Z1,1)=1

I have already tried replacing 1 in above formula with 2 and 3 but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me with the formatting?

Waqas

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to color cells, or count the number of cells with a certain value? Also, for that formula, you should not have "=1" at the end of it.

Comment: I don't want to count but want to color the cells. the above formula helped me to color the empty cells when it finds the cells value=1. It actually colors empty cells between A and D only as they have value=1

Comment: Oh, I see, you are putting that formula into the conditional formatting, sorry about that.

Comment: DO you know any other way to do what I required?

Comment: @chemicwaq Please share screen of your worksheet or at least its part - it's quite difficult to understand the task.

Comment: http://www.filesend.net/download.php?f=6ad03a9d4d1a7e231616998c07fa6d41

Comment: PLEASE SEE ABOVE LINK. If we give value 1 to cells in a row then all empty cells between those two cells will be colored. I want same thing for other numbers like 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The link seems dead so somewhat guessing the requirements (eg no overlaps) I suggest three rules (to allow a different colour for each) for blanks between 'bookends' of `1`s, `2`s and `3`s, in A1:

```
=AND(A1<>1,A2<>1,COUNTIF(A1:$Z1,1)=1)  
=AND(A1<>2,A2<>2,COUNTIF(A1:$Z1,2)=1)  
=AND(A1<>3,A2<>3,COUNTIF(A1:$Z1,3)=1)
```

each with Applies to =$A$1:$Z$1.

Comment: what about the columns between 1 and 2 or between 2 and 3? They remain blank and unedited. I understand it is hard to decipher the question, but could oneu simply add 2 more rules to the formula to account for those last two ranges?

Comment: very true. I didn't really know what the requirements were... so hard to follow. Its hard to help when OP doesn't help themselves with appropriate questions or info ;-)